# jQuery-UI accordion open one, collapse all

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I have several accordions in distinct forms of the same page. I want to open a accordion and collapse the others. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly your needs the situation is:

1. you have multiple accordion
2. when you click on an accordion tab you want to collapse possibly opened accordion

I don't replicate the solution given but I think this is still valid and fits your needs: [Close accordions if other accordian is open in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186993/close-accordions-if-other-accordian-is-open-in-jquery/13188284#13188284)